# Firebase Check Method (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I'm using Firebase Simple Login and it accepts a proper login, rejects an incorrect one, and quietly lets me log out (no idea whether it worked). What I'm wrestling with is this: When my app starts up, I need to figure out whether the user is still logged in (this would happen if they chose "remember me"). If so, I move right along, otherwise I present a login screen.

What I'm observing is that if I call the `unauth` function on the entire Firebase and then try to use the `check` method, the error returned to the block is NULL and the user email is still the same as the last logged-in user. The same happens if I use the `logout` method on the auth object.

This is a RubyMotion app, so I can play with it in the REPL and see what's going on.

UPDATE: I'm adding in the code so anyone else who comes upon this can see what's going on. It turns out to have been an idiosyncrasy in motion-firebase. I will be submitting a fix for that. In the meantime, here's what my code was:

Code to set things up:

```
def init_firebase
  @fire_ref = Firebase.new('https://my-fine-firebase.firebaseio.com')
  @auth = FirebaseSimpleLogin.new(@fire_ref)
end

def login(email, password, &block)
  status = MotionMap::Map.new({error: 'success', user: nil})

  @auth.login(email: email, password: password) { |error, user|
    status.user = user

    if error.nil?
      if user.nil?
        status.error = "no error but user is nil"
      end
      block.call(status)
    else
      status.error = error.localizedDescription
      block.call(status)
    end

  }
end
```

So call my login method responds to the Firebase callback and on completion, it in turn executes a closure in my Ruby code. This all works. The `MotionMap` stuff is simply a nice way to get hashes with indifferent access.

Now, In the REPL I can do this:

```
(main)> error = nil
(main)> f.unauth{|e| error = e}
(main)> p error
nil

(main)> error = user = nil;
(main)> a.check{|e, u| error = e; user = u}
(main)> p error
=> nil
(main)> puts user.email
=> 'my_real_email_address'
```

So the first thing I did was to unauthorize this particular Firebase reference, right? And then, I went ahead and did a check. The error was nil (NULL in Objective-C), but the user information was intact. In other words, I can't tell that my user was unauthorized.

UPDATE: Calling `unauth` on the Firebase object seems not to affect the way `check` sees the logged-in status. I did a simple fix on the logout method in motion-firebase and it appears that calling the `logout` method on the auth object actually clears the information in that object and calls `unauth` on the Firebase object. This is just my deduction from watching what's happening.

It should be noted that calling `check` (which maps to `(void)checkAuthStatusWithBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( NSError *error , FAUser *user ))block`) runs asynchronously and upon completion calls the block, with a `nil` error and a completely empty user.

Is the `nil` error the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to post some exact code that your having issues with for a more exact answer.

Firebase uses call backs to determine what state a user is in. Depending on what ruby wrapper you are using for FireBase, the implementation may differ. Firebase typically gives you three options: Success (if the user is already authenticated or just successfully authenticated), Error (something went wrong), and Else (user is not logged in). In each of these call backs you can specify what you want to do.